# Do I need to set up raid to install ubuntu server 20.04

Tags: server, raid

I have an old desk power Edge sc1430 that I'm trying to install the server software onto. But it does not see any of my discs when doing block probing. However if I go into the terminal I can see all the disks that are mounted.

So I am wondering if I have to set up a raid before I can install the server software to help see the disks that are mounted.

The reason for installing the ubuntu server 20.04 software is to run a Plex Network on a headless server.

And as a side note, I have tried installing ubuntu desktop and was able to successfully install it and it does detect all my drives.

Please excuse me if this is confusing this is my first time working with Linux servers and I may not have the proper verbiage.

Comment: Your question title does not seem related to what you wrote in the body of your question.  It's not clear what problem you are facing and it's not clear what you are asking.  Please use [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1392014/edit) to add context and details to make it clear what you are asking.  Your title should adequately describe the question you are trying to ask.

Comment: Are you talking about hardware RAID (more-or-less transparent to the OS) or software RAID? Server vs. desktop should give you the exact same hardware and partition options. The difference is mainly in what packages get installed.

Comment: thank you i got it up and running